# What the purpose of the repackaged.jar inside libs of androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0 aar?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, aar

Inside the libs directory of the aar of `androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0` their is a jar called `repackaged.jar`. What the purpose of this jar?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that one may have tried to solve some dependency issues. Compare this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557807/repackaging-library-jars-in-java#15558370).

*Edit*: I took the JAR apart and found e.g. `FlatBufferBuilder` classes and similar. As the AAR in question is a compat-library, it is likely that it depends on an older implementation of such classes and is therefore piggy-backing them in this `repackaged.jar` file.

Comment: thanks Krokomot, can androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0 work without repackaged.jar or did i absolutely need to include repackaged.jar in my project ?

Comment: Hm, I haven't worked with this library yet. But as a thumb of rule and if I havent' a reason to do it another way, I generally would include the AAR file as such into the project instead of single components. It's the purpose of Android Archive files  (https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) to serve as an all-in-one (jars, resources, native libraries etc) supplemental package. Therefore it is provided e.g. through Maven in a whole.